# SQL GROUP BY multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.id) as ratings_count, AVG(r.rating) as average_rating, b.id, b.bpm, b.producer, b.name, 
    (SELECT p.price FROM beats_pricing as p WHERE p.license = 1 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_1,
    (SELECT p.price FROM beats_pricing as p WHERE p.license = 2 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_2
    FROM beat_ratings AS r
    INNER JOIN beats AS b
    ON b.id = r.beat_id
    WHERE b.active = 1
    GROUP BY r.beat_id
    HAVING price_1 > 0
    ORDER BY average_rating DESC, ratings_count DESC
    LIMIT 50
```

I have a table of `beats`, which have multiple rows for each beat in `beat_ratings` which is a table of individual 5 star ratings. This SQL statement is used to get the most highly rated `beats`. I'm also grouping by `r.beat_id` to ensure there is only one row returned for each `beat`.

Each beat has a `b.producer`, and I only want to return one `beat` for each `producer`. I've tried adding it to the `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY r.beat_id, b.producer
```

But this returns the exact same results. How can I group by or return only unique rows based on the `b.producer`field?

Comment: If a producer has multiple beats, which one should be returned?

Comment: @Barmar their most highly rated beat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your query into a subquery, and then group that by producer:

```
SELECT *
FROM (yourquery)
GROUP BY producer
```

Comment: That's perfect, as long as I put the `HAVING price_1 > 0 ORDER BY average_rating DESC, ratings_count DESC LIMIT 50` in the outer query then it works just how I want it to. Thanks for the help